# Branch naming in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

Are there any best practices for branch naming in TFS? Currently if I'm branching from my Main to my Development folder I name the branch after the feature.

I'm not sure if this is a good way to do this or not, so was just after opinions and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the guidance by the ALM Rangers on codeplex?

https://aka.ms/vsarsolutions

Comment: Howzit, the codeplex page doesn't exist anymore either. The new home page root for ALM Guidance and extensions is https://go.beeming.net/2Lj4nli

Comment: specifically on the page you can look for "Version Control (ex Branching and Merging) Guide" which is near the bottom of the guidance section

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati, I've updated it to the new url that the rangers have to their solutions. the content is all old.... PS: A url from 5 years ago is also most likely in most cases not going to work. Something constructive to help here would have been to google "ALM Rangers on codeplex" or look at the comments I've added (not sure why I didn't edit the answer) but they have updated links.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can organize branches into three categories: Main, Development and Release. Main branch is branch from a parent with the latest changes, and Development and Release branch from Main. You can define your branch name like: ProjectName_Main, ProjectName_Dev, ProjectName_Release.

Also have a check on this MSDN article for defining branching and merging strategy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx